# Form is submitting to wrong url. how to make form action to my website

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have my website hosted. Not local. I am sending the email below.

```
@component('mail::message')

<form method="POST" action="/users/user/confirm/{{ $user->confirm_token }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

    <button>Confirm</button>
</form>


Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}

@endcomponent
```

When I get the email. I checked the form url. The url to the action is not correct. it is suppose to be https://mywebsite.com/users/user/confirm/234893h423d

this is how the form looks like in the email

-

```
<form method="POST" action="http:///users/user/confirm/234893h423d"
</form>
```

Comment: u should do this action="{{ url('/users/user/confirm/'.$user->confirm_token) }}"

Comment: @Jigs1212 string interpolation doesn't work on strings enclosed by single quotes.

Comment: thanks edited hope that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `url()` helper method:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/users/user/confirm')}}/{{$user->confirm_token }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('users/user/confirm', $user->confirm_token) }}">
```